# How to add some perspective to AI files placed in InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, shapes, workflow, information-graphics

I'm working with 50+ floor plans drawn up as AI files (Example image 1).

I need to keep the artwork intact in the AI files for future updates, but need to add perspective to these when placed in InDesign (Example image 2).

I am aware of Illustrator's 3D Rotate effect, but trying to avoid using that, as I need the floor plans in the original top view, because these get updated alot.

The perspective thing needs to somehow happen in InDesign after placing the AI files, but how?

> Example image 1

[image]

> Example image 2

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Precise isometric view

[image]

- Select *Container Frame*
- Copy height to clipboard
- Set *Rotation Angle* to -30
- Set *Shear X Angle* to 30
- Select *Content Frame*
- Paste in the height from before
- Fit frame to content

### Eyeballed axonometric view

[image]

- Select the *Content Frame*
- Rotate it to your liking
- Select the *Container Frame*
- Scale the height to your liking

Comment: Actually started appying this today and saving alot of time. It was right in front of me, but I couldn't see it :) thanks again

Comment: Good to hear @Lucian. I've always loved axonometric/isometric view, but sadly I've never had the use for this method professionally  But I'm ready if it comes!

Answer (score 3):

For parallel projection only, no other perspectives:

Apply Object > Transform > Shear. Then Scale and rotate with the normal selection tool for good apparent proportions. You can also find good numerical values for shearing, scale and rotate. InDesign remembers numerical values for repeated work.

An example of the result:

[image]

Here the shearing is horizontal 45 degrees, rotation and vertical squeezing have been made visually without numerical input.

Comment: +1, I'm not trying to steal your answer . I answered this question in the chat and @Lucian turned it into a proper question so I could post my answer.